# Show schedule for Employees instead of dates

Tags: objective-c, calendar, eventkit

For many days I am trying to figure out how to show employees on vertical columns for EventKit Calendar. I have tried all the available demos on Github and SO.

"I WANT TO DISPLAY EMPLOYEES NAMES, instead of Date Time on top"

I want to display like this:[image]

and currently I have

[image]

I have been working on

[RVCalendarWeekView](https://github.com/BadChoice/RVCalendarWeekView)

[CalendarKIT](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)

And this is my code for objective c, you can guide me for the case of SWIFT ASWELL

```
   - (void)setupWeekData{
    
    self.decoratedWeekView = [MSWeekViewDecoratorFactory make:self.weekView
                                                      features:(MSDragableEventFeature)
                                                  andDelegate:self];
    ///*MSDragableEventFeature |*/ MSChangeDurationAndDragableFeature | MSNewEventFeature | MSInfiniteFeature | MSPinchableFeature |MSShortPressNewEventFeature /*| MSChangeDurationFeature*/
    //Optional, set minutes precision for drag and new event (by default it is already set to 5)
    [MSWeekViewDecoratorFactory setMinutesPrecisionToAllDecorators:self.decoratedWeekView minutesPrecision:5];
    
    
    //Create the events
    MSEvent* event1 = [MSEvent make:NSDate.now
                              title:@"Title"
                           subtitle:@"Central perk"];
    
    MSEvent* event2 = [MSEvent make:[NSDate.now addMinutes:10]
                           duration:60*3
                              title:@"Title 2"
                           subtitle:@"Central perk"];

    MSEvent* event3 = [MSEvent make:[NSDate.tomorrow addMinutes:10]
                           duration:60*26
                              title:@"Title 3"
                           subtitle:@"Central perk"];

    MSEvent* event4 = [MSEvent make:[NSDate.nextWeek addHours:7]
                           duration:60*3
                              title:@"Title 4"
                           subtitle:@"Central perk"];
    
    _weekView.delegate                              = self;
    _weekView.weekFlowLayout.show24Hours            = YES;
    _weekView.weekFlowLayout.hourGridDivisionValue  = MSHourGridDivision_15_Minutes;
    
//    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
//        _weekView.daysToShowOnScreen        = 7;
//    }
//    else{
//        _weekView.daysToShowOnScreen        = 2;
//    }
    _weekView.daysToShowOnScreen        = 1;
    _weekView.daysToShow                    = 30;
    _weekView.weekFlowLayout.hourHeight     = 50;
    _weekView.events = @[event1,event2,event3,event4];
}
```

Comment: Is the question about using EventKit (text and tag) to create a `RVCalendarWeekView` like calendar or about how to use `RVCalendarWeekView` (images and code)?

Comment: this is about the event kit. but I want to use employee names as columns instead of dates.  event of every employee will be visible in its column. see the image above.

Comment: Have you tried anything with EventKit?